# Why are the correct values not displayed in my @Html.DropDownListFor()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am a beginner at .NET MVC and trying to do a simple task such as displaying a list of items in a dropdown list. However my current code produces a dropdown list displaying the name of the type of the items instead of the actual values. Thanks for helping out. :)

[DropDown not displaying the correct values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDY4c.png)

My code follows;

SelectArticleModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TheMakingOfAWebApplication.Models
{
    public class SelectArticleModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Article.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TheMakingOfAWebApplication.Models
{
    public class Article
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TheMakingOfAWebApplication.Models;

namespace TheMakingOfAWebApplication.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //List<Article> articles;

            SelectArticleModel model = new SelectArticleModel();
            model.Name = "";
            model.Articles = new List<Article>{
                new Article { Name = "Bananas"},
                new Article { Name = "Apples"},
                new Article { Name = "Oranges"},
                new Article { Name = "Melons"},
                new Article { Name = "Grapes"},
                new Article { Name = "Sallad"},
                new Article { Name = "Potatoes"},
                new Article { Name = "Cucumber"},
                new Article { Name = "Beans"},
                new Article { Name = "Tomatoes"}
            };
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model TheMakingOfAWebApplication.Models.SelectArticleModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Article</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Name, new SelectList(Model.Articles))) 
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: try @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Articles.Name, new SelectList(Model.Articles)))

Comment: Thanks but I can't generate the "m => m.Articles.Name" in the suggested code. I get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let your `SelectList` know what the Value and Text property names are.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Name, 
                 new SelectList(Model.Articles, "Name", "Name", Model.Name)))
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much Jamie, I really do appreciate your help allot. :)

Comment: Yes, I know it was a simple one. I am in the stage where I am trying to learn about .net mvc. I find it hard to know how to populate these  @Html.DropDownListFor() helpers properly. Are there any guidelines for how to approach these types of tasks? Should I start with reading about all the overloaded versions of the @Html.DropDownListFor() and then modify the way I package my models (top down approach)?

Comment: your model is ok.. one thing you might consider is to make your lists that are to be used in dropdowns a `List<SelectListItem>`.  this makes you define the Text and Value properties in the Controller and not have to in the View.

Comment: crazy thing is, once you finally learn how to use html helpers the next version of MVC goes in another direction and uses Tag Helpers instead

Comment: Yes, you are right, using the List<SelectListItem> in my controller instead would be a better approach. Thanks. I feel I have learned allot actually. :)

Comment: Yeah, that's the difficult thing with working in IT, one has to constantly keep up with new stuff coming out. I hope the new Tag Helpers will make it easier to populate dropdown lists in mvc. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a complex object to bind, you can specify the dataTextField and dataValueField as arguments to `SelectList`. Try following:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Name, new SelectList(Model.Articles,"Name","Name"))
```

If you have a List of primitive types like string, the overload of `SelectList` you are using would work without mentioning extra parameters.

Comment: Thank you Siva! I appreciate it allot. :) Your suggestion also works. I guess the take away from this particular problem is to understand the overloaded versions of the @Html.DropDownListFor() method?

Comment: No, we need to understand the overloaded versions of `SelectList` :)